# Rewrite Rules with question mark in ISAPI

Tags: isapi, isapi-rewrite

i have a rewrite question that need help with.
Rewrite from this URL:
    mydomain/x.cfm?color=pink&page=1

to this URL:

```
mydomain/pink--x.cfm?page=1
```

Using the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(color=.*&page=*)?$
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)--(.*)?page=(.*)/?$  shop/$2.cfm?color=$1&page=$3 [R,NC,L]
```

But it gives me pink--x.cfm not error?
Is there something wrong with my rewrite rule?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you need to rewrite from this URL: mydomain/x.cfm?color=pink&page=1
to this URL: mydomain/pink--x.cfm?page=1
the rule should be

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^color=(.*)&page=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.cfm$  /%1--$1.cfm?page=%2 [R,NC,L]
```